# Не запускается эмулятор Android 1.6 в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, arm

в Android Studio создал эмулятор Android 1.6 arm. Запускаю, и появляется ошибка о том, что "Эмулятор Android завершен".  [image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Он же уже недоступен для скачивания и вероятно 1.6 image несовместим с текущим эмулятором.

Comment: И к тому же Nexus 5 с FullHD -- не уверен что Android 1.6 вообще работает на экранах 360dp. Они гораздо позже появились.